# Formatting Phone Numbers for International SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush

Our client has asked us to create an ExactTarget Landing page which captures international phone numbers into a data extension for possible later use in SMS messaging. This leaves me with a few questions.

First, is my understanding right that I cannot use ET's Phone Data Type because that is limited to 11 characters?

Second, should the number be formatted as if you are calling from within the non-US country or from the US. For example, in Argentina, the country code is 54 and to call a Buenos Aires number from the US, would look like this: +54 9 11 1234 5678.

However, to call a cell phone from within Argentina, one needs to add a 15 like this  (11) 15 1234-5678 where 11 is the area code and 15 indicates it is a mobile number. If I am sending an SMS message from ET, does it already know the country code because of the short or long code I am using and should I then add the 15 (which is required

Third, should I use a number format or text format to get proper importing into ET's SMS Subscriber list. Does ET care whether I use (123) 123-1234 or 1231231234?

Thanks, 
Bill

Answer (score 2):

It may be best to contact your ET support representative to get a confirmation on this. From the [ET documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/mobile_messages/international_text_messages/)-

Long Codes

ExactTarget's international SMS services default to using a UK long code format, such as +44-xxxx-xxxxx. Use this number to send and receive your international SMS messages. ExactTarget also supports the German and Swedish long code formats.

> You can provision several different short codes and long codes in your
>   ExactTarget account, depending on your sending needs and the countries
>   in which you wish to operate. Note that any keywords you use must be
>   requested for each short code or long code you wish to use that
>   keyword with. Be sure to select the correct short code or long code
>   each time you request a keyword. The screenshot below shows how to
>   select the number for which you are requesting a keyword. After
>   selecting the number, you can enter the keyword and select Check
>   Availability to see if the keyword is available.

This depends on Locale as well

> The Locale type helps the ExactTarget application determine the
>   correct format for phone numbers used as part of an SMS send.

Comment: This is good information, thanks. But, unless I misunderstand, does not help me with my current question. I am asking how to save the subscriber's mobile number, not dealing with the short or long codes which I understand to be the code that subscribers use to contact the SMS service.